# Connecting Qt 5.4 With MySQL on Mac - QMYSQL Driver Not Loaded

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, sqlite, qtsql

I've seen other people with this issue, but I can't find a solution that has worked.  I've had MySQL downloaded for a while, and use it for web development, but this is my first time trying to hook it up with Qt.

This is my `main.cpp` file:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "passwords.h"
#include "signup.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QtSql>
#include <QDebug>
#include "qsqldriver.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);

QString servername = "LOCALHOST//QMYSQL";
QString dbname = "test";
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");

db.setConnectOptions();

QString dsn = QString("DRIVER={SQL Native Client};SERVER=%1;DATABASE=%2;Trusted_Connection=Yes;").arg(servername) .arg(dbname);

db.setDatabaseName(dsn);

if(db.open()){
    qDebug() << "Opened";
    db.close();
}
else{
    qDebug() << "Error =" << db.lastError().text();
    qDebug ( )  <<  QSqlDatabase :: drivers ( );
}

MainWindow w;

w.show();

return a.exec();
}
```

I've included the following in my `.pro` file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /Users/tomeldridge/downloads/mysql-5.6.17-osx10.7-x86_64/include
INCLUDEPATH += /Users/tomeldridge/downloads/mysql-5.6.17-osx10.7-x86_64/lib

INCLUDEPATH += /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xampp/sqlite/include
INCLUDEPATH += /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xampp/sqlite
```

I get the error: 
`QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7`

If I use SQLite, I get the error:
`Error: out of memory opening database`

I have tried building the driver from scratch using the code from the Qt documentation:

```
-no-sql-<driver> ... Disable SQL <driver> entirely.
-qt-sql-<driver> ... Enable a SQL <driver> in the Qt Library, by default
                 none are turned on.
-plugin-sql-<driver> Enable SQL <driver> as a plugin to be linked to
                 at run time.

                 Possible values for <driver>:
                 [ db2 ibase mysql oci odbc psql sqlite sqlite2 tds ]
```

This apparently requires you to have downloaded the Qt Source Code, which I went and did, so you can use Qt Configure.  Something went wrong along the way, and the commands I tried to use in terminal didn't work.

I also tried moving copies of the MySQL `lib` files into the Qt `lib` directory, since I saw someone who that worked for, but I didn't have any luck.

I've done several things to try and get this to work, and I've hooked up MySQL before, but I've wasted two days trying to get a database running, so any help would be awesome.